# iOS ARKit saving map across multiple sessions

Tags: augmented-reality, ios11, arkit, slam, slamdata

I am developing an app using iOS ARKit which has launched recently. I have a question if map and data that has been added can be extended to multiple sessions.

I am adding UI elements on top of map data, however if I close the app and open it again, i will have to do entire map detection and adding UI elements again. If there is a way to save the map please suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARKit save object position and see it in any next session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153564/arkit-save-object-position-and-see-it-in-any-next-session)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49153564/957768 — I forgot this question existed and wrote up a better answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

There is no [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) for accessing the data ARKit uses internally for position/orientation tracking, nor for telling ARKit to save/restore such data itself.

Comment: Is there a work around for this? Cloud support or something?